# "Cash me ousside" girl's speech

Tags: dialects, north-american-english

Danielle Bregoli, a.k.a. the "Cash me ousside" girl, [became a meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/cash-me-ousside-howbow-dah) after she appeared on the Dr. Phil Show. (See also: http://www.tmz.com/person/cash-me-outside-girl/)

Is Bregoli's speech an affected version of AAVE (African-American Vernacular English)? If not, how would you characterize it in terms of dialect?

Comment: What is the source of this quotation? What is the context?

Comment: In your own source, an African American man stated that blacks have been saying that for years, but it didn't become funny until a white woman said it, so yes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in the clip linked to in the question.

Comment: @Stoney Context: the girl (white, fourteen and working class) and her mother were on the Dr. Phil show. The mother was having problems with the girl's behavior. When the girl obnoxiously defended her behavior, members of the audience laughed at her. The indignant girl, a true brat, challenged the audience members to "cash me outside," meaning "catch her outside," which is a challenge to fight. It was the pronunciation of catch as cash (and her AAVE speech in general) that really got her the media attention.

Comment: In Ebony magazine a writer characterized the dialect as 'poorly imitated' AAVE  *Yes, as 13-year-old Black girls are ridiculed and condemned for speaking the AAVE (African American Vernacular English) that is a hallmark of their culture, for embracing the dialect that shows and maintains familiarity among their peers, a White girl poorly imitating Black speak has become a celebrity.* Interesting article bringing some seriousness to what might be laughed at: http://www.ebony.com/news-views/cash-me-ousside-girl#axzz4oSREWhkd

Comment: I heard it and I would say it was NOT an affected version AAVE. I work at an inner city hospital in Baltimore an encounter many many AA people - I have NEVER heard anyone talk like this. At first I thought she had some sort of mammoth tongue piercing causing her to have an speech impediment. Apparently this is not the case - she actually chooses to speak this way. Not sure who she is imitating but she sounds ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

## "Cash Me Outside": A Phonetic Analysis

*Note:* I am not a phonetician, so don't take the below too seriously. I'll edit this as I correct mistakes, so expect this answer to get revised many, many times.

In the famous [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkmOnEFCyI0&t=3m20s), Bregoli (now known as "Bhad Bhabie") claims to have acquired her accent "on the street." Certainly [her mother's accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTjFA2Ow2oc) in the episode is completely different and close to General American with some Southern influence. This doesn't even seem to be how Bregoli always talks; in other videos her speech is much closer to her mother's, and she does quite a bit of code switching. Some have accused her of [appropriation.](https://www.bustle.com/p/cash-me-ousside-shows-how-our-society-rewards-white-appropriation-of-black-culture-43404) Bregoli grew up in the suburbs around Miami, so I think we can speculate that accents (AAVE or otherwise) from that area are most relevant.

It does seem, to some extent, that Bregoli's speech may be an affected form of African-American Vernacular English (AAVE).
Bregoli does show some AAVE-like grammatical features.  Around 1:47, she says "I know where the car at," omitting the copula; likewise with "you asking for it" around 2:25. Around 1:05, she says "everybody know already about it," regularizing the present-tense forms of *know.* But this is hardly conclusive.

So, back to phonetics. My first pass transcription of her pronunciation of "cash me outside, how 'bout that" is:

**[kʰɛʃ.mij.aʊˈsaː  haʊ.baʊʔ.dæʔ]**

The above is imperfect; I'd probably need to do formant analysis to figure out her realization of /aʊ/. But that illustrates the main unusual features in her speech. Let's go through this piece-by-piece.

#### Catch me: [kʰɛʃ.mij]

Here the most notable change is the deaffrication of the /t͡ʃ/ sound in "catch" to /ʃ/ ("cash"). [Carter and Lynch (2015)](https://cri.fiu.edu/news/2015/professor-phillip-carter-coauthors-article-on-multilingual-miami/multilingual-miami.pdf) mentions that Cuban Spanish, which has obviously influenced Miami dialects, is often affected by this phonological process. That's my best explanation, but [in other contexts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NyMSWqIJDQ) she pronounces word-final /t͡ʃ/ in the standard way.

Her pronunciation of "me" is, surprisingly, unremarkable.

#### Outside: [aʊˈsaː]

Here, there are two odd features: the use of a monophthong in the second syllable and the omission of the word-final /d/. The reduction of /ts/ to /s/ seems unremarkable.

The first one is easy to explain; this monophthongization of /aɪ/, [as Wikipedia explains,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monophthongization) is common in both Southern white dialects and AAVE.

The second one is a bit trickier. I'm not quite sure if her final /d/ there is getting glottalized or deleted entirely, but it sounds more like the latter. [Thomas (2007)](https://repository.lib.ncsu.edu/bitstream/handle/1840.2/2062/Thomasj.1749-818X.2007.00029.pdf?sequence=1) notes that, in many AAVE dialects, morpheme-final /d/ can be glottalized or deleted entirely.[This page from UAlberta](http://www.rehabmed.ualberta.ca/spa/phonology/features.htm) says that "final /d/ glottalization" and "final consonant deletion" of this sort are "apparently unique to AAVE."  This is probably the best evidence for AAVE influence on Bregoli's speech.

#### How 'Bout That [haʊ.baʊʔ.dæʔ]

The omission of the first syllable of "about" is quite common, as is the glottalization of the word-final /t/ in "about" and "that."

It's notable that Bregoli starts the word "that" with a /d/ sound instead of the usual /ð/, making it sound like "dat". This phenomenon, known as *th*-stopping, is common in many dialects; [as Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English), these include AAVE among many others.

### Conclusions

Bregoli's speech does show evidence of AAVE (and possibly Latino English) influence. But I don't think anyone would go so far as to say that she's "speaking AAVE" in this clip, and one can debate how direct or extensive this influence is.